# How to render a <template> tag as an actual DOM element?

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently working on a script that uses [`<template>` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp) for obtaining markup that it should render. To be compatible with reactive frameworks like Vue, it uses a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to find new elements dynamically. However, the `<template>` tag is reserved in Vue for its own purposes. Is there a way to tell Vue to treat such a tag like any other tag and render it in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `is` directive in Vue for generating a dynamic component according to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is).

So effectively this would generate a `<template>` tag in the HTML DOM.

```
<div is="template">
   <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes, forgot about that one. Except you have to pass "template" as string, otherwise you get "Property or method "template" is not defined".

Comment: Yeah, fixed that in the answer